# Changing the default directory for git repositories

Tags: git, path, repository

Is it possible to change the default/root directory of where git looks for projects so you can clone a project like this:

```
git clone git@myserver.com:project.git
```

rather than like this:

```
git clone git@myserver.com:/var/www/html/project.git
```

I've  seen `git --git-dir=<path>` in the help page but it seems that it only takes effect for that particular command rather than being a global setting - and that's even if it does what I want it to do.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using ssh path, it always start in given user's home directory. So for the example in the question to work, all you have to do is set HOME directory of `git` user to `/var/www/html`.

Comment: Hooray! I went one better and made a symbolic link to the directory from my home. If I set my home somewhere else, I would have to copy the .ssh folder and all the other stuff into my web folder - which generally isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

When using the git protocol, you can set it on the server by giving `git daemon` the `--base-path` option.

Answer (score 0):

Well, before all other: you use scp-style notation, standard URLs will be better for communication

Back to question: Yes, you [can do it](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS)

> if you want to use a different format for them (such that the URLs you
>   use will be rewritten into URLs that work), you can create a
>   configuration section of the form:

```
    [url "<actual url base>"]
            insteadOf = <other url base>
```

in your example it will be

```
    [url "myserver.com:/var/www/html/"]
            insteadOf = myserver.com
```

or even

```
    [url "git@myserver.com:/var/www/html/"]
            insteadOf = myserver:
```

for using URL `myserver:project.git`